# ошибка CS0453: тип «List <Vector2>» должен быть типом значения, не допускающим значения NULL

Tags: c#, null, type-error

Ошибка CS0453:

```
   Assets\PanoramaTerrainTools\ToolExtended\ClippingOFArbitraryPolygons.cs(390,12): error CS0453: The type 'List<Vector2>' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'
```

В строке:

```
public List<Vector2>? pointVec2 = null;
```

Comment: `List<T>` и так может быть null, зачем вам тут `?`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня два взаимо исключающих списка в классе List<Vector2>? pointVec2, List<Vector3>? pointVec3;

Comment: И? Вы пишете `pointVec2 = null`, а он и так `null` по умолчанию, это обычный класс, а все классы `null`, то есть `?` где он сейчас стоит - бесполезен, как и `= null`. Другой вопрос, `Vector2` - это структура, а она не может быть `null` и тут уже можно сделать `Vector2?` чтобы возможно было в коллекцию отправлять `NULL`, но у вас странная задача, зачем в коллекции хранить null?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну у меня класс полигон, в нем либо точки типа Vector2, либо Vector3 ... тут сам класс https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1155924/178835

Comment: Знаете что я могу вам посоветовать... Если у вас рабочее решение, но вы думаете, что можно лучше, то попробуйте создать вопрос, где будет рабочий экземпляр кода, ну и подробное описание задачи. Пометьте это меткой [`[инспекция-кода]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) и если найдется тот, кто поймет задачу, то думаю помогут. Я к сожалению в векторах вообще не смыслю, но уверен, что можно обойтись вовсе без `NULL`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ответ можно пометить тэгом [инспекция-кода]?

Comment: Метки ставятся только на вопросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно объявлять список, как

```
public List<Vector2> pointVec2 = null;
```

Как уже заметили в комментариях, `List<T>` и так является `nullable`.
Если вам нужен список nullable векторов, тогда

```
public List<Vector2?> pointVec2 = null;
```

Подробнее тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: Как я его могу List<Vector2> сделать Nullable?

Comment: обновил ответ, List<T> является ссылочным типом и может быть null, как вам ответили в комментарии на вопрос.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Посмотрите внимательнее где знак вопроса у вас в коде и в ответе