# аналог на C# std :: sort(C++)

Tags: c#, c++, сортировка

[Нашёл ответ .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424626/sort-array-of-object-in-c-sharp-equivalent-of-stdsort) Но не могу понять как сортирует на C++, как написать аналогичный код на C#?

```
void PolySplitter::SortEdges(const QLineF &line)
{
    // sort edges by start position relative to
    // the start position of the split line
    std::sort(EdgesOnLine.begin(), EdgesOnLine.end(), [&](PolyEdge *e0, PolyEdge *e1)
    {
        // it's important to take the signed distance here,
        // because it can happen that the split line starts/ends
        // inside the polygon. in that case intersection points
        // can fall on both sides of the split line and taking
        // an unsigned distance metric will result in wrongly
        // ordered points in EdgesOnLine.
        return CalcSignedDistance(line, e0->StartPos) < CalcSignedDistance(line, e1->StartPos);
    });

    // compute distance between each edge's start
    // position and the first edge's start position
    for (size_t i=1; i<EdgesOnLine.size(); i++)
        EdgesOnLine[i]->DistOnLine = PointDistance(EdgesOnLine[i]->StartPos, EdgesOnLine[0]->StartPos);
}
```

[Полный код на C++.](https://github.com/geidav/concave-poly-splitter/blob/master/polysplitter.cpp)

Более полная информация по коду на C++:

```
            std::vector<PolyEdge *> EdgesOnLine;
            struct PolyEdge
            {
                PolyEdge(const QPointF &startPos, LineSide side) :
                    StartPos(startPos),
                    StartSide(side),
                    Next(nullptr),
                    Prev(nullptr),
                    DistOnLine(0.0f),
                    IsSrcEdge(false),
                    IsDstEdge(false),
                    Visited(false)
                {
                }
        
                QPointF             StartPos;   // start position on edge
                LineSide            StartSide;  // start position's side of split line
                PolyEdge *          Next;       // next polygon in linked list
                PolyEdge *          Prev;       // previous polygon in linked list
                float               DistOnLine; // distance relative to first point on split line
                bool                IsSrcEdge;  // for visualization
                bool                IsDstEdge;  // for visualization
                bool                Visited;    // for collecting split polygons
            };
    
        ...
        void PolySplitter::SortEdges(const QLineF &line)
        {
            std::sort(EdgesOnLine.begin(), EdgesOnLine.end(), [&](PolyEdge *e0, PolyEdge *e1)
            {
                return CalcSignedDistance(line, e0->StartPos) < CalcSignedDistance(line, e1->StartPos);
            });
        
            for (size_t i=1; i<EdgesOnLine.size(); i++)
                EdgesOnLine[i]->DistOnLine = PointDistance(EdgesOnLine[i]->StartPos, EdgesOnLine[0]->StartPos);
        }
        ...
        static double CalcSignedDistance(const QLineF &line, const QPointF &p)
        {
            // scalar projection on line. in case of co-linear
            // vectors this is equal to the signed distance.
            return (p.x()-line.p1().x())*(line.p2().x()-line.p1().x())+(p.y()-line.p1().y())*(line.p2().y()-line.p1().y());
        }
        ...
```

У меня код на C#:

```
static public List<ClippingOFArbitraryPolygons.PolyEdge> EdgesOnLine;
public class PolyEdge
{
    public Vector2 StartPos;   // start position on edge
    public LineSide StartSide;  // start position's side of split line
    public PolyEdge Next;       // next polygon in linked list
    public PolyEdge Prev;       // previous polygon in linked list
    public float DistOnLine; // distance relative to first point on split line
    public bool IsSrcEdge;  // for visualization
    public bool IsDstEdge;  // for visualization
    public bool Visited;    // for collecting split polygons
    public PolyEdge(Vector2 _startPos, LineSide _side)
    {

        StartPos = _startPos;
        StartSide = _side;
        Next = Prev = null;
        DistOnLine = 0.0f;
        IsSrcEdge = IsDstEdge = Visited = false;

    }
 
};
static double CalcSignedDistance(UnityEngine.Vector2[] _line, Vector2 p)
{
    // scalar projection on line. in case of co-linear
    // vectors this is equal to the signed distance.
    return (p.x - _line[0].x) * (_line[1].x - _line[0].x) + (p.y - _line[0].y) * (_line[1].y - _line[0].y);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110862/discussion-on-question-by-ivan-triumphov---c-std-sortc).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ClippingOFArbitraryPolygons.PolyEdge> EdgesOnLine;
```

Пока не проверил но вот что получилось:

```
 public class PolyEdge : IEquatable<PolyEdge>, IComparable<PolyEdge>
    {
        public Vector2 StartPos;   // start position on edge
        public LineSide StartSide;  // start position's side of split line
        public PolyEdge Next;       // next polygon in linked list
        public PolyEdge Prev;       // previous polygon in linked list
        public float DistOnLine; // distance relative to first point on split line
        public bool IsSrcEdge;  // for visualization
        public bool IsDstEdge;  // for visualization
        public bool Visited;    // for collecting split polygons
        public int PartId;
        public PolyEdge(Vector2 _startPos, LineSide _side)
        {

            StartPos = _startPos;
            StartSide = _side;
            Next = Prev = null;
            DistOnLine = 0.0f;
            IsSrcEdge = IsDstEdge = Visited = false;

        }
        public int CompareTo(PolyEdge comparePart)
        {
            return this.PartId.CompareTo(comparePart.PartId);
        }

        public int CompareTo(PolyEdge comparePart, UnityEngine.Vector2[] _line)
        {
            if (CalcSignedDistance(_line, this.StartPos) < CalcSignedDistance(_line, comparePart.StartPos))
            {
                this.PartId--;
                comparePart.PartId++;
            }
            return CompareTo(comparePart);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return PartId;
        }
        public bool Equals(PolyEdge other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.PartId.Equals(other.PartId));
        }
    };
```

И теперь вызываем сортировку так :

```
static internal void SortEdges(UnityEngine.Vector2[] _line)
{

    EdgesOnLine.Sort((A, B) =>  A.CompareTo(B,_line));  

    for (int i = 1; i < EdgesOnLine.Count; i++)
        EdgesOnLine[i].DistOnLine = PointDistance(EdgesOnLine[i].StartPos, EdgesOnLine[0].StartPos);
}
```